# OctoMap installation

Tags: ros, installation, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am quite new to ROS and Ubuntu, so this may be a silly question, but I could not solve it. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo, and I would like to install all the OctoMap packages in a separate workspace, in order to source it when I want to use it. I cloned all the folders from GitHub (https://github.com/OctoMap), but when I try to build the workspace with catkin_make, I have an error saying that the octomap main package (https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap) contains 'non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation'.
How can I solve this problem? Should I download a different version of that package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255975/octomap-installation/) by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OctoMap library is not a catkin package, so you have to cmake/make install it manually and then build the ros-related packages using catkin_make. I think there is also a binary package liboctomap-dev which you could just install instead (but which might be outdated though).

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on 2017-03-02**:
Uhm, I see. So I should copy it in the workspace/src and then install it manually, and then catkin_make at the root of the workspace? Sorry but I am not sure about all these processes, they are new to me.

**Comment by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on 2017-03-02**:
The point is that I already have some OctoMap packages under opt/ros/indigo/share (that I installed along with other things I previously installed, the robot and MoveIt!, I guess), so I don't want to overwrite them. That's why I want to do this in a separate workspace, for experimenting with it.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2017-03-02**:
Don't put it in your workspace at all (the octomap-lib, because it is not a catkin package). Only catkin-packages should go into your workspace. It will then be installed to /usr/local. However catkin package will likely use your octomap from the ros-binaries, so you might have to unistall these.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2017-03-02**:
Btw. I agree with mig's comment, why don't you use the deb-installed octomap that comes with ros (and is already installed on your system?)

**Comment by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on 2017-03-03**:
Ok, I finally installed it from debs (sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-octomap ros-indigo-octovis). Thank you.
But there is nothing that is contained here (https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap), no .cpp, no files, no nothing. Just an empty shell. How do I use it now? For opening octovis, for example.

**Comment by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on 2017-03-03**:
I asked a different question for being more specific on my problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/256065/octomap-and-octovis/
If you know the answer, please answer there. It would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why would you want to do that and not install the debians? It does not matter if they are sourced, as long as you don't start any of the octomap stuff...

To answer your question: you need to do a `catkin_make_isolated`. There are several questions about this on ROS answers which googleing reveals...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1